# There is a big gap underneath my h1 tag. I want the all texts to be in the same row as each other

Tags: html, css, frontend

im new to HTML/CSS

I have a large gap underneath my h1 tag.

I want the "Thank you for stopping by!" text to be in the same row as the email/linked texts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7EiG.jpg)

HTML:

```
   <footer class="footer">
          <div class="footLinks">

                <h1> Thanks for stopping by!</h1>
                <h2> <a href="mailto:BBBBBB@gmail.com">Email </a></h2> 
                <h2><a href="https://www.linkedin.com" >Linkedin</a></h2>
          
          </div>
    </footer>
```

CSS:

```
.footLinks  h1  {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
  
}


.footLinks{
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.footer {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there was a small tweak in the code, see if it solved your problem

```css
.footLinks  h1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;
}

.footLinks {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
   <footer class="footer">
          <div class="footLinks">

                <h1> Thanks for stopping by!</h1>
                <h2> <a href="mailto:BBBBBB@gmail.com">Email </a></h2> 
                <h2><a href="https://www.linkedin.com" >Linkedin</a></h2>
          
          </div>
    </footer>
```